# How do I update tables in SQL so that related strings match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Suppose I have 2 tables

```
Table1
ID Path
-- ---- 
1  PathA
2  PathB
3  PathC
4  PathD

Table2
ID Path  Table1ID
-- ----  --------
23 PathA 1
24 PathX 2
25 PathC 3
26 PathZ 4
```

In the above, PathX should be PathB and PathZ should be PathD

How do I sync all the path values in Table2 with values in Table 1, the tables could be large so would like to check for all values that do not match and update them.
Cheers

Using MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: Have you considered refactoring this.  By having the Table1ID in the row of Table2 you eliminate the need for the Path field in Table2.  Once you do that (forgetting any other code that may need to be changed) you won't have this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this should do the trick...

```
UPDATE Table2 SET
    Path = t1.Path
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON
    t1.ID = t2.Table2ID
WHERE
    t1.Path != t2.Path;
```

**Edit:** Sorry I believe I misinterpreted your request. I thought you wanted Table2 values into Table1. I've changed it to be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The following is I believe the simplest:

```
 UPDATE TableB SET Path = TableA.Path 
 FROM TableA
 WHERE TableB.Id = TableA.ID AND TableB.Path <> TableA.Path
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your question correctly this will update the paths on table2 with values from table1

```
Update Table2
    set path = b.path
    From Table2 a
    Left outer join Table1 b
    on a.Table1ID = b.ID
    Where ltrim(rtrim(a.Path)) <> ltrim(rtrim(b.Path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example demonstrates how you can (will) get anomalies if you do not normalize your tables.

In Table2 either store Table1ID or Path but not both, you can query for the other (perhaps recreate your current Table2 as a VIEW. Whichever column you choose for Table2, ensure you have a foreign key on it referencing Table1.

Comment: Hi,
yeah I know, but its part of a large legacy system that I wasn't part of when it was deployed to customers, but its something that I will apply in later designs.

Comment: Once you've scrubbed the data, apply the FK with ON UPDATE CASCADE referential action; if at least one of the columns is NULLable, you'll need to keep them in synch using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way

```
UPDATE TableB SET Path = TableA.Path 
 FROM TableA
 WHERE TableB.Id = TableA.ID AND TableB.Path <> TableA.Path
```